# Loading a .OBJ into Unity at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My job is to write a code which loads a .OBJ into Unity in runtime. Unity has provided a sample code in it's [wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=ObjImporter) page. I used the following code to use the class given in the link:

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Mesh holderMesh = new Mesh ();
        ObjImporter newMesh = new ObjImporter();
        holderMesh = newMesh.ImportFile("C:/Users/cvpa2/Desktop/ng/output.obj");
    }
```

I'm not getting any errors in Unity Monodevelop, but neither is the model loaded.
What may be the probable solution?

Comment: You tried debugging it?

Comment: First try importing a simple cube and isolate if it is not your obj file that have something uncommon that is not  provided in this class but I think you can't escape from debugging it to see where it is getting lost

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just creating a Mesh object is not enough. You will have to do at least two more things:

- Create a MeshRenderer component
- Create a MeshFilter component

So if you change your code to the following you should at least see your mesh if it has been successfully created.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Mesh holderMesh = new Mesh();
        ObjImporter newMesh = new ObjImporter();
        holderMesh = newMesh.ImportFile("C:/Users/cvpa2/Desktop/ng/output.obj");

        MeshRenderer renderer = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        MeshFilter filter = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        filter.mesh = holderMesh;
    }
}
```

From there on out you'd still have to assign a material (if loaded/created) and other such things, but it would be a start.

Comment: Thanks @Bart, I tried the same. Still the object doesn't appear in main camera. (I can see it in Mesh Filter tab, though)

Comment: The exact code above works (different path of course) with a simple cube .obj file I created by exporting Blender's default scene. If you're loading anything more complicated, go back to something simple. See if that will work. If it does, inspect what goes on with your mesh. If it doesn't, you'll have to make sure your own code and setup are fine.

Comment: It seems that ObjImporter is wrong. There are some code in there that don't seem to make sense and it will definitely break on large files. It uses the face count to define the size of the vertex array (which should be significantly smaller), so Unity will complain that vertex count is over 65000 when it is actually below that.

Comment: @Everts did you actually try importing the mesh directly? Does Unity not complain about it if you do? I think it actually might, given how it's likely to layout mesh data.

Comment: Importing a 30k vert mesh gives a too many vertices exception. Looking at the code, it makes sense since the vertex array length is defined by the faceData.length (?!). So even though the vert count is 30k, the array is 120k so it breaks. That importer would only work on small items as the margin would still fall under the 65k limit. For instance, a cube or a teapot still work. The same mesh runs fine in ObjReader asset for instance.