# Importing an .obj model into Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've found a couple other posts with similar questions and also a code that should work( [Loading a .OBJ into Unity at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586186/loading-a-obj-into-unity-at-runtime)) using the ObjLoader Class( http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=ObjImporter)

Unfortunately that didn't work for me since I actually receive an error, which others don't.

I get "IndexOutOfRangeException", which would normally be a simple beginner mistake using arrays, but since the code seems to work for others, I guess it is misleading and the problem lies deeper.

I guess the problem is, that I want to attach the mesh to an actual Game Object, but I can't figure out, how to do this properly.

Any suggestions appreciated.

My Code

```
        // 1. Create an controller (this will be the pivot point later)
        GameObject controller = new GameObject(bo.objectName + " Controller");

        // 2. Create an primitive object, and set it as child
        GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        sphere.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        sphere.transform.SetParent(controller.transform);
        sphere.name = bo.objectName;

        // 3. Give it a custom mesh
        Mesh holderMesh = sphere.GetComponent<Mesh>();
        ObjImporter newMesh = new ObjImporter();
        holderMesh = newMesh.ImportFile(bo.modelPath);//"C:/Users/Fuby/Desktop/Test Object.obj"
        sphere.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = holderMesh;
```

ObjImporter Code

```
List<int> intArray = new List<int>();

while (j < brokenString.Length && ("" + brokenString[j]).Length > 0)
{
  Vector3 temp = new Vector3();
  brokenBrokenString = brokenString[j].Split(splitIdentifier2, 3); //Separate the face into individual components (vert, uv, normal)
  temp.x = System.Convert.ToInt32(brokenBrokenString[0]);
  if (brokenBrokenString.Length > 1)                                  //Some .obj files skip UV and normal
  {
    if (brokenBrokenString[1] != "")                                    //Some .obj files skip the uv and not the normal
    {
      temp.y = System.Convert.ToInt32(brokenBrokenString[1]);
    }
    temp.z = System.Convert.ToInt32(brokenBrokenString[2]); //IndexOutOfRangeException
  }
  j++;

  mesh.faceData[f2] = temp;
  intArray.Add(f2);
  f2++;
}
```

Comment: A guess, does your .obj contain vertices with position, normal and UV? I think that error happens if one of these attributes is missing.

Comment: I simply created a cube in Cinema4D and exportet it as .obj... Im not realy sure what exactly the .obj contains, how can I check that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file

Comment: After removing the if-part, it worked. At least it has a form now. It's pitch black, though. I guess I removed uv and normals. So I guess you're right, the .obj is missing them. Question is...how do I solve that? I guess I'll DL some .objs and try them out.

Comment: You were totally right in the end. Once I've tried an professionally made .obj it worked like a charm. So the code stated above is perfectly fine, I simply exported it wrong somehow.

Comment: Fuby, you must apply an UV map to the object, usually that's the problem. I don't use Cinema4D, I use Lightwave, in Lightwave unless you apply a texture map to the object it has no UV by default, so I suppose the same happens on Cinema4D.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm totally new to this. I have an UVW map, but the UV thing looks challenging. I'll try another modelling program, since C4D doesn't even seem to import the UV maps of working objs ...

Comment: UV mapping is always challenging, is one of the hardests parts to do, that and rigging. I used some time ago this little utility, it may help you: https://www.uvmapper.com/

Comment: I created an cube with a realy simple UV map (only drawing some lines)... still, this didn't solve it. So it's either not UV map relativ, or C4D is simply unable to export it correctly.

Comment: If Cinema4D doesn't exports it right try with Blender, is open source and works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The code above works. Just like Gusman said, the .objs needed an UV map. The problem was the C4D export for .objs, though. Just use Blender for the export. It will add an .mtl file and it will work!

Thanks to Gusman for the support.