# I want to import an external fbx file to a stand alone unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, exe, fbx

Hello how can I import an fbx file to a unity build project without using unity engine.so I can access the new fbx file from the exe that I have built.

Comment: Please give us some more info about what exactly is that you are trying to do. For now, as far as I can understand is that you want to add a ".fbx" file after you build your game right? if that's so I don't think that you can do that but you can add a ".obj" file by loading it from file or downloading from the web.

Comment: See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586186/loading-a-obj-into-unity-at-runtime) this might help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So can I convert the fbx file to obj and add it?.

Comment: Yes, basically in modelling software you can import an ".fbx" file in and export that file as an ".obj" you can download a blender that's free. good luck

Comment: i want that algorithm integrated to the exe file so i can drag and drop the fbx file so it get converted to obj and then get loaded in the project

Comment: you can check this link for [ObjeImporter](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=ObjImporter) or take a look at the answer down below.

Comment: I tried the below answer and it worked fine. Thank you. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this [link](https://github.com/gpvigano/AsImpL) It will work for sure. It can handle all formats like fbx, obj, glb, gltf etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This helped me loading the .obj file from desired path.You are a life saver ;). sorry for the late update. Now i need to find a way to save the obj file in project so i can access the file without importing again.Working on that  :) .

Comment: Download the file into persistent datapath using unitywebrequests and use the plugin to load the obj file. The obj will remain in the persistent data path so next time you can check if the file exists before downloading.

Comment: This plugin didn't support fbx file.